# How to turn element into jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

How to turn the event.currentTarget into jQuery object or something like that so I could then use jQuery's addClass method on the object? I know I could just do like: event.currentTarget.className += ' .class', but I was wondering how to work with the event target with jQuery.

```
$('.class').click(function(event) {
    Class.down($(this).parent().prev().attr('alt'));
    Class.style($(event.currentTarget));
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(event.currentTarget).addClass("classname");
```

Comment: oh, i didn't expect it to work $(event.currentTarget) this way. Thanks!

Comment: According to http://help.dottoro.com/ljeqmgmn.php, event.currentTarget this is not supported on IE.

Comment: That's precisely why jQuery was created. To normalize browser inconsistencies like this. My example works in IE because jQuery has solved that problem.